# Semantic UI React: How to change components properties dynamically if they used enum?

Tags: reactjs, dynamically-generated, semantic-ui-react

Here is the thing, I'm trying to use states, to change Semantic UI react (v 0.81.1)components dynamically, but it is simple when true or false, but if required certain value, I can't use them

State value

```
   state = {
      gridColumnWidth: 14
    }
```

Grid usage

```
 <Grid>
       <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column width={this.state.gridColumnWidth}>
            <Message header='Header'content='Content'/>
            </Grid.Column>
       </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
```

Error

```
Type '{ children: Element; width: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & GridColumnProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type '{ children: Element; width: number; }' is not assignable to type 'GridColumnProps'.
    Types of property 'width' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '2 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5...'.
```

Is there any tricks?

Comment: Weird, seems to work fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wk1jowpv68

Comment: @Colin well, seems like it's magic. I don't even know where to look. Search bring no result >_<

Comment: Are you using vanilla React? Why is there a `public` keyword?

Comment: @Colin no I'm not, and public left from my experiment with props, thanks, didin't notice. I clear it, but there is no difference. Still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, semantic ui react not always want to work with stats and required const values such as props.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Column width={this.props.width}>
           <Message header='Header'content='Content'/>
        </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

This helps, maybe will be useful for someone in the future.